# Error while installing jdeveloper 12 c in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, java, oracle-12c

Since .exe file is not working directly i extracted `jdev_suite_122110_win64.exe` file and executed the command in command prompt as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309685/jdeveloper-error-cmd-property-not-found-in-autorun-inf)

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar DISKCNT=1 JRE_COMPONENT=oracle.jdk,oracle.jre
```

But i am getting an error in command prompt

> Invalid variable(s): DISKCNT,JRE_COMPONENT

is this is the problem with windows 10 installation?
is there another way to install jdeveloper in windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I found using the generic installer and running from an admin level command prompt via

```
E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin> java -jar e:\downloads\jdev_suite_122120.jar
```

worked ok (amend for your environment and java versions).